# ansi c fread 16-bit integer and fwrite it as an ascii textfile

Tags: c

I have a binary file that contains 16-bit integer data and i want to convert it to ASCII readable data.

My question is how do I use `fread(&buffer,sizeof(buffer)` or `16,1,fp);` to read the file and use again `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/7, 1, file);` to write the data to a file.

16 in `fread` is 16-bit and wants to know where it goes or in what form it goes and if in fwrite I will put `7` for 7-bit.

Please provide a code snippet example in C. I want to have the resultant file to be an ordinary readable text file.

Comment: "binary file that contains 16-bit integer data" Big Endian or Little Endian?

Comment: And: are it signed ints or unsigned ints?

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code? And btw, note that you can use code formatting for code snippets here at SO, and it would make your question much more readable. Also, "please provide a code snippet" (without showing what you have tried or other code for context) kind of questions often aren't received well by the SO crowd...

Comment: Here is a downer: neither in `fread` nor in `fwrite` can you use a random **number of bits**. Reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have many things that are confusing.

Assuming `buffer` is a magically sized properly to fit the file `uint8_t` array, you can read it in (from a file `fopen()`ed in *binary mode*) using:

```
fread(buffer, sizeof buffer, in);
```

That'd give you all of the bits in `buffer`, if it doesn't fail.

Then, the output is simply:

```
FILE * const out = fopen("numbers.txt", "wt");
if(out != NULL)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof buffer; i += 2)
  {
    const unsigned int here = buffer[i] + 256 * buffer[i + 1];
    fprintf(out, "%u\n", here);
  }
  fclose(out);
}
```

This assumes little-endian byte ordering in the binary file. Swap the indexes in the `here` assignment for big-endian. It also assumes unsigned 16-bit numbers.

Comment: Psst: `"%hu"` and/or cast the argument.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks, that was needlessly confusing. Now using `unsigned int` to move around that complexity.

Comment: The here will be silently promoted to unsigned int. I still like the h modifyer ;-) BTW: you are assuming bigendian here...

Comment: I think my file is little endian. Ihave tried the code from unwind as below

Comment: i think my file is little-endian byte.i tried the code as from unwind

Comment: this is my code #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp,*out;
  char *buffer;
size_t i = 0;
fp=fopen("c:/GSM/GSM.txt", "rb");
if(out != NULL)
{
 fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer),1, fp);
}
out = fopen("c:/GSM/res.txt", "wt");
if(out != NULL)
{
   // buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*Size);

  for( i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i += 2)
  {
    const unsigned int var = buffer[i] + 256 * buffer[i + 1];
    fprintf(out, "%u\n", var);
  }
  fclose(out);
}
fclose(fp);

}

Comment: @wildplasser I'm not convinced my code assumes BE. The first integer's least-significant byte comes from `buffer[0]`, and then has 256 * `buffer[1]` added in. That seems little-endian to me.

Comment: this is my code #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp,*out;
  char *buffer;
size_t i = 0;
fp=fopen("c:/Gosam/input.txt", "rb");
if(out != NULL)
{
 fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer),1, fp);
}
out = fopen("c:/Gosam/res.txt", "wt");
if(out != NULL)
{
   // buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*Size);

  for( i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i += 2)
  {
    const unsigned int var = buffer[i] + 256 * buffer[i + 1];
    fprintf(out, "%u\n", var);
  }
  fclose(out);
}
fclose(fp);

} but it returns the following error .exe has stopped working.windows is checking the solution to the problem.

Comment: @user3559566 Please don't post code in comments; edit the question instead.

Comment: @user3559566 That said, your bug is that `buffer` is just an uninitialized pointer. Read my answer again about what I assumed for `buffer`, and make it so.

Comment: @unwind Yes, you are right, of course. It is big-headian.

Comment: @unwind Minor: Why `const` in `const unsigned int here`?

Comment: @chux Why not? It's not changing once being given its value -> it should be `const` to signal this to the reader. Always `const` everything that can be `const`, with the possible exception of scalar function arguments (since doing so is kind of pointless).

Comment: @unwind Interesting idea.  What about `out` as `FILE * const out` making it a `const pointer to FILE`?  It is not changed, once it is assigned.

Comment: @chux That's true! I'm a bit lax when it comes to pointers, but am trying to adopt that style since I really think it makes sense to `const` what can be `const`. I'll edit.

Comment: @unwind Using `const` where it is not strongly needed, but added for clarity/style is something that a post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com may provide some good feedback.  I am not convinced yet on its value versus cost. I do like new ideas though.

Comment: @chux What would be an example of code where `const` is "strongly needed"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54641/discussion-between-chux-and-unwind).

Answer (score -1):

after adjusing my code as below the result i get unsigned int,since am expecting data result with alphabetical characters.what additional code can i add to turn it alphabetical?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
       {
    FILE *fp,*out;
  char buffer[256];
          size_t i = 0;
            fp=fopen("c:/Gosam/input.txt", "rb");
            if(out != NULL)
           {
            fread(buffer, sizeof buffer,1, fp);
              }
        out = fopen("c:/Gosam/res.txt", "w");
if(out != NULL)
{
   // buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*Size);

  for( i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i += 2)
  {
    const unsigned int var = buffer[i] + 256 * buffer[i + 1];
    fprintf(out, "%u\n", var);
  }
  fclose(out);
}
fclose(fp);

}
```

these are my results but i want to turn them to alphabetical strings.

```
263
4294966987
4294967222
4294967032
64
4294967013
73
4294967004
90
4294967028
83
4294966975
37
4294966961
5
4294966976
82
4294966942
4294967022
4294966994
11
4294967024
29
4294966985
4294966986
4294966954
```

Comment: Looks like you have inconsistent signed/unsigned too.